# how to add photos into checkin for foursquare app in android

Tags: android, image, foursquare

i m doing foursquare plug in from my android application in this i can do check in and can add a tip by using the following code.

for check in :

```
Result<Checkin> result = getFoursquareApi().checkinsAdd(venueId, null, getString(R.string.checkin_msg), null, null,null,null,null);
```

for add tip :

```
Result<CompleteTip> resultTip = getFoursquareApi().tipsAdd(venueId, Appsconstant.SOCIAL_NETWORK_MESSAGE, "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRpdDBUIVfZo3tcyuNKZU_2lHjvMri6ChfQ03DetZITYPi-HI9-RA");
```

but in tip i have given the url for image. but its not add in the tip. what mistake i have done?  and how to add image with tip. plz any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't say you can add an image specifically, just that you can add a "url of interest" to this tip. Which is what you are doing

ref: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/tips/add

Comment: k. Is there any source code for post photo with the tip or with the check in. yes means can give me a sour code for tat

Comment: i used the following code for add image. 
Result<Photo> resultImg = getFoursquareApi().photosAdd(null, null, venueId, null, null, null, null, null, data);

Comment: but the value for resultImg.getMeta().getCode() is 400 and the resultImg.getMeta().getErrorDetail() is Invalid Photo format. what is the correct photo format for do tis.

Comment: finally i got answer to add photo by following code

    Result<Photo> resultImg = getFoursquareApi().photosAdd(null, tipId, null, null, null, null, null, null, data);

in this have to give data as byte array value of the selected image.